# Python. while createing list from func result, it returns me None

Tags: python, list, loops

Hello I have the following small function

```
import pandas as pd           
lst = []                 

def test(val):               
    lst.append({'value':val})
    return pd.DataFrame(lst) 

value = test('6')         
lst = lst.append(value)                         
print(lst)
```

when I run this, lst is None. However, I would like that after each loop it has been extended.

I tried also to do :

```
a = []           
a.append(value)
```

but after each run it just returns me the value that I passed in function, it removes the previous passed value

Comment: lst = lst.append(value) 

You assigned the return value of append to lst.  The return value of the append function is None.

I don't see anything wrong with a.append(value)

Comment: but after each run it returns only the value that i have passed to function, but if i run the code with other values, it does not extend it

Comment: just stick with your first snippet, and change `lst = lst.append(value) ` to `lst.append(value) `

Comment: "after each run" can you describe what you're actually doing?  a=[] should not be in your loop, if it is that would cause it to overrite the variable as an empty array.

Comment: there isn't actually a loop though. The script as shown simply appends one value to the list. I'm wondering, after reading again, if the OP is actually trying to persist the list between different runs of the same script. If so, we need to know more details of the actual use case to figure out the best way to do that.

Comment: There is no loop actually. I just want to append the each value that i passed to the func, but it is still overwrittes the values. For example if first I run the function with test('1'):, it returns me list with '1', and next time when i run it with test('2'). i want to see appended list with ['1', '2']. but it returns me ['2']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was almost correct, here's a fixed version:
(Edited after your request)

```
import pandas as pd           


def test(val, ls):
    ls.append({'value': val})
    return pd.DataFrame(ls)


lst = []
print(test('6', lst))
print()
print(test('7', lst))
print()
print(test('8', lst))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
>   value
> 0     6
>
>   value
> 0     6
> 1     7
>
>   value
> 0     6
> 1     7
> 2     8
> ```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I dont want to call function each time separately with new value

Comment: thank you, Is there way to gain this result without calling function separately with new value? can we call function once, then change just value which passes from func from 6 to 7,and then get list ['6', '7']?

Comment: @Sascha Hmm, it's not really clear to me what you mean. Try to explain it in a different way maybe? I will gladly help if I just understand your intentions :)

Comment: i mean to gain the result you call function 3 times with different arguments. But is there a way to call function once with '6', then just change 6 to 7 in the same line, each time by changing value too see that it get appended to the list, if i want the list with 10 values i have to call function 10 times(10 separate lines), but is there way to call once, and just change the value (in one line). I hope i could explain myself this time :)

Comment: @Sascha How would that work? First you'd have a line `value = '6'`, then you would backspace over it and type `value = '7'` and then backspace over it and type `value = '8'`? And after all that run your code? Ofc it wouldn't work.

Comment: i want to run it with 6 then backspace over it and type value = '7' then run it again, each time to save the result and add new result on it

Comment: @Sascha That's not really how python (or any) programs work. When you run the program it starts with a clean slate, remembering nothing from the past times it was run. You'd have to store the past values in a file if you would want to do it that way, but that's a completely different question then.

Comment: yes you are right, i can succeed it with jupyter notebook but not with pycharm. Thanks!

Comment: @Sascha Yeah, jupyter notebooks work very differently than normal python programs.